# reporting ARDL results in R

Tags: r, stargazer, modelsummary, ardl

I'm working with time series data and have run an ARDL regression using the ardlBound function from the dLagM package. I tried to export my results using stargazer; however, I believe stargazer is not readily compatible with ardlBound output.

Is there a way of reporting this output as a nice-looking reproducible table in R?

Below is sample data and code:

Thanks very much!

```
library(dLagM)
data(M1Germany)
data <- M1Germany[1:144,]
results <- ardlBound(data = data , formula = logprice ~ interest + logm1 , case = 2 , 
                   max.p = 3, max.q = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) can summarize the `ARDL.model` object stored in `results$ARDL.model`:

```r
# load libraries
library(dLagM)
library(modelsummary)

# fit model
data(M1Germany)
data <- M1Germany[1:144,]
results <- ardlBound(data = data , formula = logprice ~ interest + logm1 , case = 2 , max.p = 3, max.q = 3)

# create table
modelsummary(results$ARDL.model)
```

[image]

(Disclaimer: I am the `modelsummary` maintainer.)

Comment: I did not know about this package, thanks very much, it looks very helpful!